# problema con una función de ajax en php al cargar la página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

En el siguiente código, envío al carrito de la compra un producto mediante ajax
el problema es la última función que la utilizo para que me recargue los datos en el carrito y la página, si la pongo no me ejecuta las primeras funcione.

Código:

```
function vuelo(){

$("#a").effect('transfer', { to: $('#b') }, 1500, anadir_productos);
}

function anadir_productos(){
$("#b").effect("bounce",900);
document.getElementById('player').play();

var nombre_producto=document.formu_compra.nombre_producto.value;
var precio_producto=document.formu_compra.precio_producto.value;
var cantidad_producto=document.formu_compra.cantidad_producto.value;

//var datosForm=$("#formu_compra").serialize();

$.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"compra/mostrar_compra.php",
    //data:datosForm,
    data:{"nombre_producto":nombre_producto,"precio_producto":precio_producto,"cantidad_producto":cantidad_producto},
    success:function(resp){
        $("#mostrar_compra").html(resp);
        $("#mostrar_compra").show("fast");
        }

});

}
//$("#mostrar_compra").load("compra/mostrar_compra.php");

$(function(){   
    $.ajax({

        url:"compra/mostrar_compra.php",

        success:function(resp){

            $("#mostrar_compra").html(resp);
            $("#mostrar_compra").show("fast");

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

mira esto para que veas bien lo que sucede http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ asi deberia quedar ...

```
$(function(){
        function vuelo(){
            $("#a").effect('transfer', { to: $('#b') }, 1500, anadir_productos);
        }
        function anadir_productos(){
            $("#b").effect("bounce",900);
            document.getElementById('player').play();
            var nombre_producto=document.formu_compra.nombre_producto.value;
            var precio_producto=document.formu_compra.precio_producto.value;
            var cantidad_producto=document.formu_compra.cantidad_producto.value;
            //var datosForm=$("#formu_compra").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"compra/mostrar_compra.php",
                //data:datosForm,
                data:{"nombre_producto":nombre_producto,"precio_producto":precio_producto,"cantidad_producto":cantidad_producto},
                success:function(resp){
                    $("#mostrar_compra").html(resp);
                    $("#mostrar_compra").show("fast");
                }
            });
        }
        //$("#mostrar_compra").load("compra/mostrar_compra.php");
        $.ajax({
            url:"compra/mostrar_compra.php",
            success:function(resp){
                $("#mostrar_compra").html(resp);
                $("#mostrar_compra").show("fast");
            }
        });
    });
```